# GZip all files in a folder

Tags: python, gzip

I have compiled a code that can open an .GZ file and extract that to a .txt file
the following code works

```
import os       
import gzip
import shutil
extension = ".gz"
dir_name = 'C:\\test'
dest_name= 'C:\\test\Extract'
os.chdir(dir_name) # change directory from working dir to dir with files

for item in os.listdir(dir_name): # loop through items in dir
    if item.endswith(extension): # check for ".gz" extension
         file_name = os.path.abspath(item) # get full path of files
         with gzip.open(file_name, 'rb') as f_in:
                 with open(file_name+ '.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
                     shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

But the code writes in the same directory , I am not able to add the dest_name in the following line

```
with open(file_name+ '.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
```

Comment: `os.path.abspath` of what? current dir. So this step is useless. You need `os.path.join(dest_name,item)` instead. don't use `chdir`. it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip ".gz" from the file name and join it to `dest_name` before adding the extension. Changing the working directory is usually frowned upon because its global to the program and it can get confusing what directory you are referencing over time. The `glob` module works well for simple file matching and returns an absolute or relative path to the file.

```
import os       
import gzip
import shutil
from glob import glob

extension = ".gz"

# issue: backslash is python's string escape character. You can get the
# backslashes with raw strings (r'c:\\test') or double escaping ('c:\\\\test'),
# or just use a forward slash and let python figure it out ('c://test').

dir_name = r'C:\\test'
dest_name= r'C:\\test\Extract'

# issue: glob is well-suited for listing files like this. It returns a full relative
# path to the file. chdir is frowned apon because it is global to the program.

for file_name in glob(os.path.join(dir_name, extension)): # loop through items in dir
     with gzip.open(file_name, 'rb') as f_in:
         # issue: strip off the .gz extension and add the dest folder
         base_name = os.path.basename(file_name)
         new_name = os.path.splitext(base_name)[0] + '.txt'
         with open(os.path.join(dest_name, new_name), 'wb') as f_out:
             shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```